# What does this ending scenario mean?

Tags: mass-effect-3

One of the ME3 endings involved

> killing Shepard and thus gain control of Reapers. If Shepard is dead, how can s/he control the Reapers?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's like "the reapers gain the same ideals and etc. that Shepard had, meaning they'll do the same things Shepard would do."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When describing the Control ending, we have the following conversation

> Kid: You will die; **you** will control us but you will lose everything you have.
>
> Sheperd: But the Reapers will obey **me**?
>
> Kid: Yes.

(emphasis mine)

Saying that Shepard personally will control the Reapers implies that something of Shepard's consciousness will continue to exist to have that control. The part about losing everything also supports this because loss only means something to a consciousness that continues to exist.

The part saying that Shepard will die could mean a couple of things. It could mean that his body will die but his consciousness will somehow survive, perhaps either in the Citadel or distributed among the Reapers. Considering what the characters in the game have accomplished technologically (especially AI) and how much more advanced the glowing people were, this is not an unlikely possibility.

Another interpretation is that Shepard's body will be kept alive but he will have to stay at the controls forever. If this means that he can never again have contact with the outside world, then to everyone else it would be like he is dead, and he could never go back to life as he knows it.

The point is that the kid implies that Shepard's consciousness will continue to exist in some state while controlling the Reapers and it is likely within the Citadel's power to do this in a way that is consistent with Shepard "dying" in some sense.

Answer (score -4):

Well, actually, it's not as Mr. Smooth said (just my opinion, btw). The "control the reaper" choice is marked as blue in the ending scene, since it's the last attempt of the reapers to trick you (and thus completing their indoctrination towards Shepard). Shepard needs to be killed to do so because that would merge his mind with the reaper's, and Shep must join them completely. Dead just refers to its organic part i think, since with that ending you see him flickering, but still you chose to control them

There are lots of information about the indoctrination theory (which is, imho, the fittest for the ending) and you can start reading about that from [this link](http://www.gamefront.com/mass-effect-3-ending-analyzing-the-indoctrination-theory/). There are also some nice videos on youtube to enforce this theory

Comment: Yes but the indoctrination theory is just a fan theory, it's not from the developers, so this answer is all speculation.

Comment: What's the point of indoctrinating a dead man?

Comment: @MrSmooth there's no theory about the developers either, so it's just the fittest now. Since they dropped the theory of the dark matter and a lot of things, it's just the one that makes more sense. Yet, it's just speculation, with a lot of signs supporting it. kotekzot: did you play ME1 and ME2? If so, you know that shepard is half-synthetic. He's not being killed, just his organig part. If the organic shepard dies, then the indoctrination is complete and only the synthetic shepard remains, as a part of the reapers: the reapers win :)

Comment: The synthetic "part" is nothing more than a set of high-tech prostheses.

Comment: @kotekzot: nope. You should have played ME2, you'd learn a lot of things about shepard and "being synthetic". Shepard isn't just a simple biotic with implants, but i can't spoil you this, you should play the second chapter of the game by yourself. With that, i think you'll understand better the difference between "shepard dies" and "organic part of shepard dies".

Comment: ps: Shepard wakes up after
Destroy, because the Reaper's hold is diminished. Shepard does not
awake in the other 2 "endings" because you are fully indoctrinated by
the choices you made to allow the Reapers to win. "Assuming Control!"

Comment: I have played all of the games, please don't assume anybody who disagrees with you is an ignorant boor. Nothing in the canon has indicated that the synthetic prostheses are in any way autonomous or capable of autonomy.

Comment: Never assumed anything like that. But still, in ME2 you're a cyborg, face it. You were dead, dismembered as they state in the beginning. Ceberus gets you back by working two years on you. You're full of cybernetic (remember the scars at the beginning?). As i stated before, it's just my opinion. The reapers don't have the same ideals as shep, they don't want him to modify their behaviour, they want him to join them. Their purpose is to purge all organinc every 50k years, so there's no point in using shep's organic form. But they probably want a more powerful reaper thanks to sheps mind.

Comment: What will "join" the reapers after Shepard's organic parts are destroyed is a pile of scrap metal. According to Miranda and later the Illusive Man, his brain was left untouched for fear of screwing up his mojo, so even his memories, let alone his faculties, have no chance of being preserved by magical cyborg parts.

Comment: How can you say that? Shepard's mojo remains inside his brain, indeed. Becoming a reaper himself, he won't need anything else but his mind. Which, if he chooses to join the reapers, will become fully indoctrinated. If this doesn't make any sense to you, it shouldn't make any sense also that shepard remained death for two years. He should be decomposed, and without his original mojo, as you call it, since it's brain decomposed. This is how you view it, according to your comment.

Comment: You're right, the fact that they resuscitated a decomposed corpse makes about as much sense as a clone having the same tattoo as the original. Yet the idea of reapers playing mind games with him if all they needed was a pile of cyborg parts, instead of just killing him, which is something easily done if they were close enough to be indoctrinating him all the time, makes markedly less sense. And why would they flee after "completing the indoctrination", considering Shepard's magic juice was the only thing giving the races any hope of survival? It just makes no sense. P.S. use @nick please.

Comment: What you're discussing is a fan theory, as has been stated. And this is fine _so long as you have significant proof for it_, however, what you have here is a description of the theory and a link to a page about the theory. Pull in some of the evidence listed, and support your theory in your answer. It also is good to show areas in which your theory might be lacking, as this shows that this is assembled based on evidence and you are aware of any short comings. When you are posting a theory as an answer, you're going to need __significant__ evidence for us to consider it a good answer.

Comment: Isn't every single answer posted going to be a fan-theory, unless it can specifically quote a developer explaining what the ending means?

Comment: @Sterno the problem is not exactly that this is a fan theory, but that there is no real evidence that this theory is the correct one. If someone does have evidence (dialogue, for example) that their theory is the correct one, then I at least would not have a problem with it as an answer.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Yes, but notice that *no other answers have been posted*, specifically because IMO no one can really back up their interpretation with evidence. Don't get me wrong, I don't agree with this theory either. Downvotes are fine if you think it's wrong. This just seems to have generated an awful lot of comments arguing about it. And I'm not sure any answer can avoid these problems.

Comment: @Sterno I don't dislike this answer because I think it's wrong (even though I do). I dislike this answer because it's based on a fan hypothesis that has no more support than the obvious interpretation, and basically seems to contradict the entire point of the story. It has a lot in common with conspiracy theories and it should attract doubt for the same reasons.

Comment: look into the eyes of the illusive man in me2, of saren in the first me and shepard's near the end of me3... 3 circles, signs of indoctrination... also, characters talking about the indoctrination during the whole game describe what shepard lives in person. anyway, i said it's just a personal opinion, there was no need to downvote it, or theres no point for anybody risking any posting in this place.

Comment: I looked at the video of Shepard's eyes at the end. The glow in his eyes could just as easily be explained by his looking into something glowing. In general, the indoctrination theory seems to fit facts to the theory and ignore any evidence against the theory. Anyway, the problem with your answer *is* that it is unsupported opinion. Just because you say it is opinion, that doesn't magically make it helpful.

Comment: It's not the glowing, it's the shape, the three circles with one bigger than the other two. Recurring, in indoctri characters. Also, also other theories are not supported, but at least the indoctrination is 1) supported by clear facts in the game 2) the only one kept alive from ME1 to ME3. Remember when in ME2 they talk about the dark energy of the universe? Everybody expected that to come back in ME3, but it's been dropped and not mentioned anymore. If you pay close attention when playing ME-series, you'll see a lot of evidence pro-indoctri (why not killing shep with the beam, otherwise?)